# How to display validation error as list item?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i show each error of validation_errors() as a list item in codeigniter. i have tried this code below:

```
<?php
if(validation_errors()){
    $errors = [validation_errors()];
    foreach($errors as $error){
        echo '<br><li class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
        echo validation_errors();
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

But it showing all errors as one list item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the error delimiters. E.g.:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>');
```

More info in the [Form Validation section](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters) of the Codeigniter manual.

Comment: Great - please accept my answer if that is the case. Thanks.